# Is my network necessarily hacked?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

On two occasions on different PCs I found strange network locations. During this time I have a weird Wifi problem where my speed pointed by a speed test fluctuates constantly: no two speed tastes will show the same numbers (I mean approximate. Not exact) even though the condition remain the same and even when one executed immediately after its predecessor.

The network locations that I don't recognize have in it's name a router I don't have of a different company. This is how it looks:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohX1zqu2nKOgScFwJm7DjLSDeV6
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohX1zqu2nKOgSbruUkWS2b8esMh
Is it a hack? And if yes so what is hacked?

Comment: There's only a router and a DLNA Server that may well be the same physical device.

Comment: Determine how many devices you have on wireless. Download nmap, scan the network for any devices that will respond. My guess is that someone has hacked your wpa2/psk. Report back with what you find on the network.